# How to animate hide and show functionality

Tags: android, kotlin

I have viewpager having 2 items on second item i want to show button translating from downwards on swiping back to first item.
Below is my code:

```
  pager.registerOnPageChangeCallback(object : ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback(){
        override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
            super.onPageSelected(position)
            if(position == 1){
                signIn.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                signIn.animate().translationY(signIn.height.toFloat())
            }
            else{
                signIn.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                signIn.animate().translationY(signIn.height.toFloat())
            }
        }
    })
```

How can I implement the above functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`signIn` won't move in Y direction because you are feeding it the same value - `signIn.height.toFloat`.

On top of that, you are making the `signIn` button `INVISIBLE` before you try to animate. You won't see any animation.

Here is how I would do it. Say, I want to hide the `signIn` button with vertical slide (to bottom) + `fade out` animation.

```
if (position == 1) {
// SHOW
// assuming that the button is gone before showing it
    signIn.setTranslationY(100); // setting the starting Y position of the button 
    signIn.setAlpha(0f); // zeroing the alpha 
    signIn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // now we can make it visible and start animating
    signIn.animate().setDuration(500)
.translationY(0) // Y goes down from 100 to 0
.alpha(1f) // alpha goes form 0 to 1
.start();
} else {

// HIDE
    signIn.animate()
    .setDuration(500)
    .translationY(100)  // it animates Y of the button from 0 to 100
    .alpha(0) // animates alpha from 1 to 0
    .withEndAction(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
// this code runs when the animation ends. Every time when you hide a 
// button with an animation, you should set its visibility to `GONE` not 
// `INVISIBLE` because, `INVISIBLE` buttons can still be clicked which may 
// produce undesired flow in your app
            signIn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }).start();
}
```

PS. The code snipped I wrote is in Java, you can still copy and paste it to you Editor and it will automatically convert it to Kotlin.

Comment: That's exactly how I do it. Just instead of translation, I use scaleY and scaleX and the effect is fabulous.

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't just set `visibility` to `INVISIBLE` immediately before you animate it, you will be animating an invisible view, aka it will not show the animation. Instead, make it invisible *after* the translation ends.
2. You are translating `Y` with a positive value each time. The view will eventually end up outside of the screen. You should be doing a negative translation in one animation, and positive in the opposite animation.
3. Even better, instead of changing `visibility`, why don't you just animate `alpha` *with* the `Y` translation.

**EDIT:**
From [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/reveal-or-hide-view#CrossfadeAnimate)

```
private fun crossfade() {
    contentView.apply {
        // Set the content view to 0% opacity but visible, so that it is visible
        // (but fully transparent) during the animation.
        alpha = 0f
        visibility = View.VISIBLE

        // Animate the content view to 100% opacity, and clear any animation
        // listener set on the view.
        animate()
                .alpha(1f)
                .setDuration(shortAnimationDuration.toLong())
                .setListener(null)
    }
    // Animate the loading view to 0% opacity. After the animation ends,
    // set its visibility to GONE as an optimization step (it won't
    // participate in layout passes, etc.)
    loadingView.animate()
            .alpha(0f)
            .setDuration(shortAnimationDuration.toLong())
            .setListener(object : AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animator) {
                    loadingView.visibility = View.GONE
                }
            })
}
```

Now, you just need to add your `translationY()` to the `animate()` chain, like this:

```
pager.registerOnPageChangeCallback(object : ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback(){
    override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
        super.onPageSelected(position)
        if(position == 1){
            signIn.apply {
                alpha = 0
                visibility = view.VISIBLE
                animate()
                    .alpha(1f)
                    .translationY(signIn.height.toFloat())
            }
        }
        else{
            signIn.animate()
                .alpha(0f)
                .translationY(-signIn.height.toFloat())
                .withEndAction {signIn.visibility = View.GONE}
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Could you please tell me how can I implement this in my code.